# AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I would like to applicate a function (gaussian_filter) to my dataset with  `map`

here is a part of my code

```
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(vertical_flip=True)
training_set = datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/train/',target_size=(224, 224), batch_size = 2)

train_dataset = training_set.map(gaussian_filter, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

but I find this error

```
AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Help please, how change the code?

Comment: I don't know if you could solve it, but an alternative is to use the `preprocessing_function` when declaring the `datagen`, there you can put a function that will modify all your images in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

you can import your dataset with

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()
```